# 3th order Linear System Constructing

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have a homework but cannot solve it. I Cannot found useful information about my current topic.

Construct a 3rd order linear system and create a state equation. Two roots must be complex. one root must be a real number. apply 2 * cos(t) + t + 1 function to solve. First condition would be as desired.

Please help me :( 
Any help is appreciated.

I found these website about second order functions:
https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/SecondOrderSystems

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the given function is to be a solution of the equation to be constructed, you could select the characteristic roots to be $\pm i$ for the cosine term and $1$ for the arbitrary real root. Then
$$
(D-1)(D^2+1)f(t)=(D-1)(t+1)=-t
$$
so that $f$ is a solution for
$$
f'''(t)-f''(t)+f'(t)-f(t)=-t
$$